# How to use fpga-arria10-passive-serial driver in Linux?

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, intel-fpga

I have a board that has an NXP iMX8M-Plus processor and an Intel Arria 10 GX FPGA on it.
I want to configure the FPGA using the iMX8M-Plus processor through passive serial interface of the FPGA. I use custom yocto based image which has Linux Kernel v5.4 for the system and I have noticed that this kernel has special drivers for the operation that I needed and the driver is in `./drivers/fpga/altera-ps-spi.c` file.

I added following line to Linux Kernel defconfig before compiling to include the driver:

```
CONFIG_FPGA_MGR_ALTERA_PS_SPI=y
```

And changed Device Tree file as explained here `./Documentation/devicetree/bindings/fpga/altera-passive-serial.txt` in the Kernel source code by adding following lines:

```
/ {
    ...
    ...
    altera_region {
        compatible = "fpga-region";
        fpga-mgr = <&altera_spi>;
        firmware-name = "test.rbf";
        #address-cells = <0x1>;
        #size-cells = <0x1>;
    };
};

/* Verdin SPI_1 */
&ecspi1 {
    status = "okay";

    altera_spi: altera-spi@0 {
        compatible = "altr,fpga-arria10-passive-serial";
        spi-max-frequency = <80000000>;
        reg = <0>;
        nconfig-gpios = <&gpio5 0 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        nstat-gpios = <&gpio4 31 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        confd-gpios = <&gpio4 20 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;          
    };        
};
```

So far it is ok, the linux boots properly and I have following folder under `/sys/class/fpga_manager` folder.

```
root@localhost:/sys/class/fpga_manager/fpga0# ll
total 0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep 23 12:38 consumers
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Sep 23 12:38 device -> ../../../spi1.0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep 23 12:38 name
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Sep 23 12:38 of_node -> ../../../../../../../../../../firmware/devicetree/base/soc@0/bus@30800000/spi@30820000/altera_spi@0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Sep 20 10:45 power
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep 23 12:38 state
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep 23 12:38 status
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Sep 20 10:44 subsystem -> ../../../../../../../../../../class/fpga_manager
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep 23 12:38 suppliers
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep 20 10:44 uevent
```

My problem starts here. Basically I couldn't find any documentation or an example about how to use this driver. I have an `rbf` file generated by Quartus and simply I should be able to send this file to the FPGA over this driver. Do you have any idea about what should be the next step that I need to follow?

Thank you.

Comment: The usual way is to define a `compatible = "fpga-region";` node in the device tree (see the [bindings](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/fpga/fpga-region.txt)). That could be fully populated in the original device tree, or left mostly empty to be filled in by a device tree overlay. But the mostly empty version should at least have a `fpga-mgr` property set to the phandle of your FPGA manager node: `fpga-mgr = <&altera_spi>;` and have `#address-cells`, `#size-cells` and maybe `ranges` properties.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thank you for the comment. I updated the device-tree accordingly, you can see it in the question updated. But FPGA is still unprogrammed.

Comment: Is the firmware file in /lib/firmware ?

Comment: "test.rbf" is in the /lib/firmware folder yes.

Comment: I think the main problem is that the handling of "fpga-region" nodes seems to be heavily tied in with devicetree overlays. When a device tree overlay that targets the fpga region device tree node is loaded, it triggers a full or partial (if supported) reconfiguration of the FPGA. There is a non-mainline mechanism for loading devicetree overlays from userspace, but it requires kernel patches (this mechanism is supported by kernels for raspberrypi, beaglebone, etc.). For unpatched kernels, some external module code needs to use `of_overlay_fdt_apply()` to apply an overlay.

Comment: Another option is for some external module to interact with the FPGA bridges and FPGA manager directly, bypassing the FPGA region stuff. E.g. `of_fpga_mgr_get()` or `fpga_mgr_get()` to get a reference to the FPGA manager, `of_fpga_bridge_get_to_list()` or `fpga_bridge_get_to_list()` to get references to the bridges, `fpga_mgr_lock()` to lock the manager, `fpga_bridges_disable()` to disable the bridges, `fpga_mgr_firmware_load()` or `fpga_mgr_load()` to load the firmware, [continued in next comment]

Comment: [continued from previous comment] `fpga_bridges_enable()` to re-enable the bridges, `fpga_mgr_unlock()` to unlock the FPGA manager, `fpga_bridges_put()` to put references to the bridges, `fpga_mgr_put()` to put reference to FPGA manager.

Comment: BTW the kernel patches I mentioned for loading DT-Overlays from userspace (via configfs) can be found at [topic/overlays](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/geert/renesas-drivers.git/log/?h=topic/overlays).